# How can I add an email address Subject Alternative Name (SAN) in certtool's request template file?

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509, csr, gnutls

On places like [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/certtool.1.html), they say you can add a subject alternative name to a `request.cfg` file like so:

```
# A subject alternative name URI
#uri = "http://www.example.com"
```

I don't want it to be a URI, though. I want an email address field.

I don't see anything about this. How can I make the subject alternative name an email address in my request template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
subjectAltName = email:myEmail@email.com
```

Source: [On certificates, what type should E-mail addresses be when in subjectAltName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172239/on-certificates-what-type-should-e-mail-addresses-be-when-in-subjectaltname)