# Kafka authorization - Email address in certificate subject name converted with OID

Tags: apache-kafka, authorization, oid

We use mTLS authentication between clients and Kafka cluster and some ACLs configured on topics.

A client has in his subject name the email address, like:

```
Owner: EMAILADDRESS=user@my-domain.com, CN=my-service, OU=my-ou, O=my-org, L=my-loc, ST=my-state, C=my-country
```

But when the client calls kafka cluster we see the email address converted with his [OID code].

```
[2022-07-13 10:37:32,549] INFO Principal = User:1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#3uR2XK21ru2nwVymHN9u4B7wQCs4wrhcPavdGktA,CN=my-service,OU=my-ou,O=my-org,L=my-loc,ST=my-state,C=my-country is Denied Operation = Write from host = 10.10.10.2 on resource = Topic:LITERAL:my-topic for request = Produce with resourceRefCount = 1 (kafka.authorizer.logger)
```

Could someone explain me why this happen and how to get the email address literal instead?

[OID code] https://oidref.com/1.2.840.113549.1.9.1

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get the email address as a literal because Kafka parses the principal DN (Distinguished Name) as described in [rfc2253](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2253.txt), which doesn't support the EMAILADDRESS attribute. Unsupported attributes are encoded as in your example.

The next step depends on what you're trying to achieve.

- If you are trying to use the email address in the ACL rule, then you can do one of:

  1. if you can, issue certificates where the email address is in one of the supported attributes, such as within the CN.
  2. use a script to encode it and get the correct value, which you can use as-is in the ACL rule.
- If you don't mean to use the email address, and instead you mean to use other attributes which appear as literals (like the CN), you can either:

  1. If you have access, the best option is to issue certificates without an email in the subject name and create ACL rules accordingly.
  2. Another option might be to use [Kafka ssl principal mapping rules](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz_ssl:%7E:text=Customizing%20SSL%20User%20Name) to strip the email address and
     leave the rest for use in ACL rules. This rule should do the work:

  > RULE:^1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=.*,(CN=.*)/$1

Furthermore, EMAILADDRESS oid is deprecated as mentioned here: https://oidref.com/1.2.840.113549.1.9.1 altNames should be used instead. You can see an example here: [On certificates, what type should E-mail addresses be when in subjectAltName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172239/on-certificates-what-type-should-e-mail-addresses-be-when-in-subjectaltname).